# AWS Cloudwatch Metrics - How to Format a Number in Dashboard Metric to more than two decimal places

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm building a metric for the success rate of my API gateway and I'm trying to get more that 1-2 decimal places. I want to make sure that less than 99.9999% are successful. (Ultimately to set an alarm), but I would like to show this detail in the dashboard.

Is there some kind of value formatting syntax available. I have been digging around in the docs and haven't found anything.

```
{
    "metrics": [
        [ { "expression": "100*(1-(m1+m2/m3))", "label": "Success Rate", "id": "e1" } ],
        [ "AWS/ApiGateway", "4XXError", "ApiName", "my_webhook_api", "Stage", "prod", { "id": "m1", "visible": false } ],
        [ ".", "5XXError", ".", ".", ".", ".", { "id": "m2", "visible": false } ],
        [ ".", "Count", ".", ".", ".", ".", { "id": "m3", "visible": false } ]
    ],
    "view": "singleValue",
    "region": "us-west-2",
    "stat": "Sum",
    "period": 2592000,
    "setPeriodToTimeRange": true
}
```

Basically, I want the picture below to say 99.8XXXXX (6 decimal places)

[image: AWS Metric Widget Should say 99.8xxxxx]

Comment: Are you asking for a way to trigger an alarm when it's not successful/successful? Or you're trying to create a metric in the cw logs, with some sort of filter? Let's say whenever you get logs that has more than two decimal places of success rate, you want to trigger an alarm?

Comment: @Kulasangar I edited the post and added a picture. I just want the widget in my dashboard to display to 6 decimal places.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to accomplish this with Metric Math. Multiply by 1000000 `FLOOR` the result to get an integer then divide by 1000000 to get a floating point number again.

```
FLOOR(1000000*(100*(1-(m1+m2/m3))))/1000000)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the new-style CloudWatch UI (activated by the "Try out the new interface" link in the top-right corner) there's an **Options** tab where there's an option to "Show as many digits as can fit, before rounding", see the screenshot:
[image: CloudWatch Number graph options]

As an alternative, open the **Source** tab and add the following option to the top-level object (in the provided example this can be after the line with `setPeriodToTimeRange`): `"singleValueFullPrecision": true`.

This doesn't let you control the number of decimal digits, but achieves the goal of displaying numbers with high precision.